# DataTables Responsive is not being applied in my symfony project

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables, twig, responsive

I am in charge of maintaining an application and I am trying to apply responsiveness to a datatable, I have tried the different ways that the documentation provides but nothing works, when reducing the size on the screen the green button that allows me to see the information does not appear or apply the other responsive options, but instead I have a scrollbar but this is not the goal.

```
{% extends "FactelBundle::Layout.html.twig" %}
{% block css %}
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link href="{{asset('recursos/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
<link href="{{asset('recursos/bower_components/datatables-responsive/css/dataTables.responsive.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
{% block panel_title %}
<i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Usuarios
<div class="pull-right">
    <a href="{{ path('usuario_new') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary link-boton">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            Nuevo
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="dataTable_wrapper table-responsive col-lg-12">  
    <table class="table" id="">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellidos</th>
                {% if not is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <th>Email</th>
                {% endif %}
                {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <th>Emisor</th>
                {% endif %}
                <th>Rol</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
           
                <th>Actions</th>            
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ path('usuario_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.username }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ entity.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.apellidos }}</td>
                
                {% if not is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <td>
                    {{entity.emisor.razonSocial}}
                </td>

                {% endif %}
                <td class="rol">{{ entity.getRolesString }}</td>
                <td>{%if entity.isActive %}<button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-success link-boton">Activo</button>{%else%}<button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-danger link-boton">Inactivo</button>{% endif%}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('usuario_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" title="Editar">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary link-boton">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger link-boton accion" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" type="button" accion = "{{entity.id}}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    </button>
                     {{ form(deleteForms[entity.id], { 'attr': {'id': entity.id } })}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    {% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script src="{{asset('recursos/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('recursos/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('recursos/js/script.js')}}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

The project is in a Symfony 2 .twig file
I have tried with Bootstrap and Jquery UI.
Inside the file inspector I see that it refers to other files that are not found in the `script` lines of the twig file: Jquery Ui, Jquery 1.12, Bootstrap 3.3

Comment: Where is the DataTables [Responsive JS](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js) library? You can build the latest versions of all the downloads you need by visiting the official DataTables [downloads](https://datatables.net/download/index) page and selecting the options you want - including Responsive (towards the bottom of the page) and Bootstrap. (Bootstrap 3 is very old, if that is what you are using.)

Comment: Also, why is your table's ID empty (`id=""`)? And where is the DataTable actually initialized (`$('#the_missing_table_id').DataTable( { ... } );`)? The code does not appear to actually be _using_ DataTables.